# If Cell Value Equals Decimal Then Change Font Colour

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for what I believe to be a fairly simple code but can't seem to figure it out.
Effectively I want someone to enter values into a predetermined range of cells.
Once they've completed entering their values I want them to hit a "Save Button".
As part of the validation check I want two things to happen:

1. If their range of cells contains decimal/fractional numbers I want the numbers they've entered in incorrectly to change to colour Red.
2. And finally, once they've corrected their entry I want the numbers to revert back to their original Black colour.

So far I've been trying to workout the first code (unsuccessfully) and haven't been able to think through the second part of the code.

```
Sub ChangeColorNotNumeric()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    'identify the range to search
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("Hello")

    For i = rRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step 10
        'loop through all the cells in the row
        For Each rCell In rRng.Rows(i).Cells
            If Not IsNumeric(rCell.Value) Then
                'delete the row and go to the next one
                rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rCell
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered a Conditional Formatting Rule based upon a formula like `=INT(A1)<>A1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use VBA instead of conditional formatting, you're example is quite easy to complete.  When the function is re-called (when the end-user presses the Save button again), the function will restore the black font/transparent cell color for all cells that are now correct.

Your loop also had an incorrect step value.  I also removed the Exit For since I would think you would want all incorrect values in all columns of a row to get shown as bad, rather than just the first column that was bad.  You didn't indicate if negative numbers are acceptable or not.  If negatives are acceptable then you should review the difference between Int and Fix functions of VBA; they both truncate fractional values but handle negative numbers slightly different one from the other.

Are you using the Excel VBA debugger?  Just using the debugger would have clued you in that the first For statement was always exiting instead of looping since the Step value was not negative.

```
Public Sub ChangeColorNotNumeric()
Dim i As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRow As Range
Dim rRng As Range

'identify the range to search
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("Hello")

For i = rRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    'loop through all the cells in the row
    For Each rCell In rRng.Rows(i).Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(rCell.Value) Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf rCell.Value <> Int(rCell.Value) Then
            rCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            rCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next rCell
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there for the most part this works well, however I forgot to add that in my original post, my worksheet is protected, therefore while running this code it will not highlight the incorrect cells red currently. How can I counteract this without removing the sheet protection?

Comment: It was a worksheet protection setting, allowing me to format cells. This now works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with *Conditional Formatting*.
First, select the cell(s) you want to format.
At the *Conditional Formula* dialogue box, select `Use a formula to determine which cell to format`.

Then use this formula referenced to the first cell in your selection.
`=(A1-TRUNC(A1))<>0`
That is assuming you're formatting cells A1.
Set the desired format when condition is met, in your case text color changes to Red.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the data validation to ensure that you only allow whole numbers. They won't be able to enter a decimal number to begin with.

Comment: For all those telling me about data validation, appreciate it, I've done it, however data validation can be easily broken via copy paste, drag and fill methods etc. I'd prefer VBA since it's robust. Thanks.

Comment: @pnuts okay, will do next time. Thanks.